# Why can't I find the terminal or the software center anywhere?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I just realised that the terminal that appears when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is xTerm and not the usual purple terminal that I get. Also, both the Terminal and Software Center have disappeared from my dash. Neither can be found when searching for Terminal or Software Center by name. They have just disappeared. This has only happened in the last few minutes and I can't recall exactly when they disappeared. What happened?

Comment: What have you been installing..?

Comment: @DevRobot Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was installing Virtual Box 5.

Comment: @DevRobot VirtualB5 from their website, for 14.04, which leads to a page in software centre (Not the one that first appears when seaching for vitrual box through software centre)

Comment: You probably mean "from the `.deb` package"

Comment: VirtualB5 or Virtual Box 5?

Answer (score 9):

The purple terminal is `gnome-terminal`, you can call it from `xterm`. If it was uninstalled for whatever reason, install it again from within `xterm`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

For the Software Center (package `software-center`) do the same:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the package name is software-center, but I can't verify it right now.

Comment: Yes, it's `software-center`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Why you presume it was uninstalled?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when installing Virtual Box. The error was, that I was loading the wrong package, 32-bit instead of 64-bit. After the "installation" the terminal and the software center disappeared. I got back the software-center by

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```